# Is it possible to hide the appmenu like MS Windows can?

Tags: 12.10, unity

The global menu seems to be not optimal for desktops, in my opinion. So i disabled it.
Now i'm wondering if it is possible to hide the appmenu like MS Windows does.
Of course, it can't treggered by pressing "ALT", because the HUD uses this key. But is it even possible ?

PS: Using currently 12.10

Comment: You mean to hide the top panel?

Comment: No, i mean the app menu located on top of the window (under the title). Like i said, i disables the global menu. So the menus are on the "classic" position.

Comment: Now the menu is no longer in the top panel, it is attached to the window (like on windows xp). So what you are asking is if there is a way of hidding the menu attached to the window, and clicking or pressing a certain key will reveal it? I am just trying to make sure I understand before answering.

Comment: Yes you're right. But on Windodows (i think since Vista) the menu is hidden until you press "ALT". So i want these position, but not having the mneu all the time :)